# How to fetch more than 40 nicknames from this API

Tags: php

I'm beginner in php.
This is my code snippets:

```
$nicknamelist = "";
$summonerlist = $nicknamelist;

$url = "http://prod.api.pvp.net/api/lol/$region/v1.4/summoner/by-name/$summonerlist?api_key=$Riotkey";
$JSON1 = file_get_contents($url);
$Data = json_decode($JSON1, true);

foreach ($Data as $SummonersArray)
{
    array_push($Summoners, array("summonerName" => $SummonersArray["name"],
            "summonerID" => $SummonersArray["id"]));
}
```

$url allow only 40 names at once.
How to get data if in $nicknamelist is more than 40 nicknames?

Comment: You are sure that their API allows multiple user per request? You have to do pretty sure multiple requests or not?

Comment: use cURL with POST method for large data

Comment: Check with the API provider, and look at the rate limits, then tell us that.

Comment: Yes I'm sure. Maximum allowed at once is 40.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can chunk the input array into arrays of at most size 40 with [`array_chunk`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php) and then iterate over the single chunks:

```
<?php
$nicknamelist = array('test1', 'test2');
$region = 'xxx';
$Riotkey = 'xxx';

$Summoners = array();
$nickname_chunks = array_chunk($nicknamelist, 40);
foreach ($nickname_chunks as $chunk) {
  $summonerlist = implode(',', $chunk);
  $url = "http://prod.api.pvp.net/api/lol/$region/v1.4/summoner/by-name/$summonerlist?api_key=$Riotkey";
  $JSON1 = file_get_contents($url);
  $Data = json_decode($JSON1, true);

  foreach ($Data as $SummonersArray) {
    array_push($Summoners, array("summonerName" => $SummonersArray["name"],
            "summonerID" => $SummonersArray["id"]));
  }
}
```

Please see that this can exceed [the rate limit](https://developer.riotgames.com/docs/getting-started) very fast. Check the linked page for instructions in how to circumvent possible issues, if you want to request a lot of data.

Comment: So now I must convert my $nicknamelist to array because in my code $nicknamelist is string.

Comment: Would be the easiest solution I suppose. `explode(',', $nicknamelist)` does the trick.

Answer (score -2):

It depends on the API.
If it does not allow you to put a pagination parameter, you won't be able to get more than 40 results.